# Is there a way to stop the HomePod timer alarm remotely?

Tags: siri, homekit, homepod

I have many HomePod mini (at least one in every room/corridor). And after I went upstair to my bedroom I noticed the downstair HomePod mini (assuming in the living room) got triggered by it’s timer or countdown.

There seem to be no option anywhere in Home App.

Even for cases where you might be a long distance from the device, it’s worse of a second HomePod in my bedroom or corridor just responds with ***There’s nothing to stop*** or with ***there’s nothing to mute*** or ***there’s nothing playing*** due to it being closer to me than the one currently alerting.

On occasion this can be highly inconvenient (say music or a movie was loud but now quiet) causing the downstairs unit to blast a timer alarm at full volume past midnight. Other scenarios could be, that I’m away from home and receive a call from my neighbour saying my Siri alarm is triggering him/her.

I did fount this [Same Question](https://www.reddit.com/r/HomePod/comments/nsb2uy/any_way_to_remotely_kill_a_timer_thats_gone_off/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf) on Discord, but no working answers there… :(

Is there a way to stop the HomePod timer alarm remotely?

Comment: Workaround would be a smart plug that you could turn off remotely.

Comment: Interesting workaround. But I feel bad to do this. Tell Siri to off the plug that will kill (turn off) Siri. Against my morale lol

Comment: Does restarting the device from home app work?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is now possible with Home app on iOS 15.5. Tested on my iPhone just now.

It works in macOS 13 Home app too.

Also, you can just say to Siri, "stop living room HomePod timer".

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel timers from the Home app, at very least when on the same Wi-Fi:

1. Select the HomePod
2. Scroll down to "Timers" (below "Alarms")
3. Delete the timer that you want to remove

Comment: Your solution would work only if the timer is still counting down. But I needed to stop already triggered timer (Ex.: Set to countdown 5 min and after those 5 min passed).

Comment: @GediminasJeremiahGudelis Do you mean when the alarm is making a sound?

Comment: Ah, so cancelling an actively chiming alarm - yea I'm not aware of being able to do that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you have Siri on a local device (like an iPhone).

“Hey Siri, turn off the alarm in the living room” (or whatever your ringing alarm pod is labelled as) works.

Comment: Does it work when the alarm is ringing? or before it goes off?

Comment: When the alarm is ringing.